# nVidia PRIME with Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

I am currently using Ubuntu MATE 14.04 and tried a new way of setting up my Optimus laptop (Asus G46VW, GTX 660M and i7-3630QM with Intel HD 4000). After installing nvidia-352 nvidia-settings and nvidia-prime, I also ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
sudo prime-select intel
```

So right now my screen is always in sync. When starting Steam with

```
 optirun steam
```

the framerate is very-very good! The performance is higher than what I saw with PRIME. Is this expected or did I find something new here? I've been searching all around the forums for similar ideas but mostly people are asking which one should they use - never saw anyone try both at the same time.

Some more details: before I started tinkering with this, I had a basic prime setup. My first step was installing bumblebee then rebooted, chose the nouveau drivers, rebooted, checked the drivers again, nvidia-304 was selected, changed it to nvidia-352, rebooted again, then removed nvidia-prime, I got a black screen at the login, so I opened a console, reinstalled nvidia-prime and chose the intel card and after that reboot, everything works as I explained above.

Also, I tried to replicate this with Linux Mint 17.3, but no luck there: I get X errors if using intel with optirun and no vsync if using nvidia with optirun.

If this could be a breakthrough, what can I do to make it happen?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question but since you've already experienced it, how's the battery life when you tried both at the same time?

Comment: My laptop also works better on bumblebee, did you further investigate?